# line break in math mode within longtable environment

Tags: amsmath, longtable

I have a long mathematical expression within parenthesis which is larger than the column width that I have specified for my table. How do I force it to break the expression onto a new line?

```
       \begin{center}
       \footnotesize
       \begin{longtable}[l]{>{\raggedright}p{2.25cm}>{\raggedright}p{9cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
       \hline
       \textbf{Text}  &     \textbf{Maths} &     \textbf{Text} \\ \hline
       \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from previous page}} \\
          \hline
                     \textbf{Text}  &     \textbf{Maths} &     \textbf{Text} \\ \hline
           \endhead
            \multicolumn{3}{r}{{-- Continued on next page}} \\
           \endfoot
          \endlastfoot
  TEXT 1 &  $\dfrac{\kappa_{nf}}{\kappa_{f}}= 1+3\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}-1}{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}+2}\right)\phi+ \left(3\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}-1}{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}+2}\right)^{2}+\dfrac{3}{4}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}-1}{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}+2}\right)^{2}+ \newline \dfrac{9}{16}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}-1}{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}+2}\right)^{3}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}+2}{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{2\kappa_{f}}+3}\right)....\right)\phi^{2}$ & Text 2\\

      \hline
      \end{longtable}
      \end{center}
      \normalsize
```

Ideally I would like the break to occur at the just before the \dfrac{9}{16}

I have tried putting a \begin{split} and \end{split} but I get a latex error (Package amsmath Error: \begin{split} won't work here

Has anyone got an idea?

Cheers

Comment: `center` has no effect on a longtable, other than introduce vertical space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't break a line inside `\left...\right`, so write `\right.\newline\left.`, where the dot means "invisible delimiter".

By the way, breaking at 3/4 gives a better-looking result.
Personal opinion: I prefer operators be tied to the right operand, so instead of having + signs at the end of line, I'd rather like to place them at the beginning, correctly aligned.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{P{2.25cm}P{9cm}P{3cm}}
\hline
\textbf{Text}  &     \textbf{Maths} &     \textbf{Text} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Text}  &     \textbf{Maths} &     \textbf{Text} \\ \hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{3}{r}{{-- Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
TEXT 1 &  $\dfrac{\kappa_{nf}}{\kappa_{f}}
          = 1 +
          3\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}-1}{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}+2}\right)\phi +
           \left(3\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}-1}{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}+2}\right)^{2}+\right.\newline
\left.     \dfrac{3}{4}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}-1}{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}+2}\right)^{2} +
           \dfrac{9}{16}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}-1}{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}+2}\right)^{3}
           \left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{\kappa_{f}}+2}{\dfrac{\kappa_{p}}{2\kappa_{f}}+3}\right)....\right)\phi^{2}$ & Text 2\\

\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Presto! Cheers dude! Can the same be done with a long fraction?

Comment: Explain better. Placing `\newline`s between objects is easy, but I think that break inside a fraction it's a very very bad idea, and gives a very poor result.

Comment: Like you say it gives a poor result so I think I will just break the fraction into two parts rather than try to split it over two line. Might need to do some algebra!

Answer (score 2):

A variant, using the `nccmath` package (for its mediumsized fractions) and the `ltablex` package, that allows for page breaking within tabularx environments. I use an `aligned` environment for the long math formula, and replace the `\left … \right` pairs with `\Biggl … \Biggr`. The `makecell` package allows to give some vertical spacing around the formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array,ltablex}
\keepXColumns

\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\makegapedcells

\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright}p{2.25cm}| >{\footnotesize}X| >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}%
\hline
\textbf{Text} & \textbf{Maths} & \textbf{Text} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Text} & \textbf{Maths} & \textbf{Text} \\ \hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{3}{r}{{-- Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
TEXT 1 &
$ \begin{aligned}\MoveEqLeft[-1.5] \mfrac{κ_{nf}}{κ_{f}}= 1+3\Biggl(\mfrac{\mfrac{κ_{p}}{κ_{f}}-1}{\mfrac{κ_{p}}{κ_{f}}+2}\Biggr)ϕ + {}\\[-1ex]
& + \Biggl[3\Biggl(\mfrac{\mfrac{κ_{p}}{κ_{f}}-1}{\mfrac{κ_{p}}{κ_{f}}+2}\Biggr)^{\!2} + \mfrac{3}{4}\Biggl(\mfrac{\mfrac{κ_{p}}{κ_{f}}-1}{\mfrac{κ_{p}}{κ_{f}}+2}\Biggr)^{\!2}
+ \mfrac{9}{16}\Biggl(\mfrac{\mfrac{κ_{p}}{κ_{f}}-1}{\mfrac{κ_{p}}{κ_{f}}+2}\Biggr)^{\!3} \Biggl(\mfrac{\mfrac{κ_{p}}{κ_{f}}+2}{\mfrac{κ_{p}}{2κ_{f}}+3}\Biggr)....\Biggr]ϕ^{2}\end{aligned} $
& Text 2\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]